# Windows Server 2003r2 + PowerShell2.0 = accountExpire?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2003, powershell-2.0

Very simple question. How do i get this string:

> $endDate = "01/14/2088"

Some code here to tranform the current form of date into numbers which AD can accept.

Into `$accountExpire` which can be inserted via:

The Format is like this "129955896000000000" A big ass number.

> $newUser.put(“accountExpire”, $accountExpire)

REMEMBER! It's Windows 2003r2 we are talking about.

Comment: Found the answer: $accountExpire = [string](Get-Date $endDate).ToFileTime()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to solve it in PowerShell :

```
$endDate = "01/14/2088"
$dtEndDate = [datetime]::parse($endDate)
$ldtEndDate = $dtEndDate.ToFileTimeUtc()
$ldtEndDate
153693504000000000
```

You can download a tool called [SlxWinDFI](http://www.silogix.fr/conversion-dentiers-64-bits-en-dates-relative-ou-absolue.aspx) (sorry in french) that allow you to verify and to compute long date from calendar dans duration.